# undefined local variable for message when creating delete link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For my inbox I created a way to delete multiple messages from the inbox. Now I am trying to setup how to delete the message the current user is viewing. There should be a link at the bottom of the message that reads `Delete`. When user clicks the `Delete` link the message will be deleted and user would be redirected to their inbox.

When adding the code to the controller, I am now unable to even view the inbox message. I get a `undefined local variable or method "message" error` when trying to view message, with the page title of `NameError in Messages#show`.

Anyone know how I can fix this problem?

New code added to controller:

```
   def destroy
     @message = Message.find(params[:id])
     @message.destroy
     flash[:notice] = "Successfully deleted message."
     redirect_to user_messages_path(@user, @messages)
   end
```

Messages controller:

```
Class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_user

  def show
     @message = Message.find(params[:id])
     @message.readingmessage if @message.recipient == current_user
   end

   def destroy
     @message = Message.find(params[:id])
     @message.destroy
     flash[:notice] = "Successfully deleted message."
     redirect_to user_messages_path(@user, @messages)
   end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = current_user
    end
end
```

show.html:

```
<%= link_to "remove", message, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

routes:

```
Dating::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  get 'edit' => 'users#edit'
  get "/profile/:id" => "users#show"
  get "profile/:id/settings" => 'users#edit'
  match 'settings/:id' => 'users#settings'

  resources :users
  resources :sessions
  resources :password_resets
  resources :galleries
  resources :photos
  resources :searches

  resources :users do  
      get 'settings', on: :member  
  end

  root to: 'users#new'
  root to: 'galleries#index'

  resources :users do |user|
    resources :messages do
      collection do
        post 'delete_multiple'
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use `@message` in your link_to like this:

```
<%= link_to "remove", @message, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: Do you have a `:messages` resource in your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: Yes, routes added to original post just now.

Comment: try: `[@message.user, @message]`

Comment: how's about `[current_user, @message]`?

Comment: and remove `|user|` from routes

Comment: How about you post your routes file. Also, is this link_to inside a loop or a form_for?

Comment: Thank you! That works! Though I don't understand why that work and the use of the brackets as opposed to what I had earlier.

Comment: cause it's a nested route! read the docs or find the `Rails for Zombies 2` tutorial in pdf online for a nice explanation